# Wix - Creating a Windows Share - but why can it be deleted?

Tags: windows, wix, share

This question might not necessarily be 100% related to WiX, but ANY help would be appreciated. I have a WiX msi that along with installing stuff, it creates a Windows Share based on past in folder path:

```
   <Directory Id="TOPFOLDER">
    <Component Id="cmpTOPFOLDER" Guid="{9E6C5291-XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-6FB6A12DFE99}">
      <CreateFolder />
      <util:User Id="Everyone" Name="Everyone"></util:User>
      <util:FileShare Id="fsTOPFOLDER" Description="My Shared Folder" Name="My_Share">
        <util:FileSharePermission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
      </util:FileShare>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```

This works fine and the windows share is created and thus everything ticks along nicely .... BUT on some sites ( & in our office ) now and again, when they are using our app that accesses the share, they will find that the windows share has gone ?!

So I was wondering, firstly if I have set the share up correctly in WiX and if so, can anyone please let me know WHAT might cause a windows share to be deleted ( except for a user going in and deleting it ) - all other shares on that PC are still there ?!

Thanks in advance,

Chris.

Comment: ... how do you know a user isn't deleting it?

Comment: well obviously can't be 100% certain - but most of our users don't even know what a share is - but also it's happened once on a test VM of mine - and I know I haven't deleted it :)

Comment: So it's created by an admin (if the installer requires elevation; if not, make it so)... instead of giving everyone all rights to it, give read/write rights only.  So only the admin can delete it.  If it's deleted, then an account with admin rights did it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Will - I will do that, but unfortunately that will only help ( potentially ) our new customers, because we have two setup.exes - one that is run from the DVD which creates the windows share and copies in the installers and then the second setup.exe that is run from the Windows share to actually install the product.  Most users doing an upgrade will only run the second setup.exe - so they'll never run the one that creates the share again.